# How to fix "Failed to load class org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder" error on Maven?

Tags: java, macos, tomcat7, maven-3, intellij-14

I  was trying to deploy a web app but I can't deploy my web app, I am working with:

Intellij IDEA 14.1.4

OS X YOSEMITE 10.10.4

Maven 3.2.5

Tomcat 7.0.63

In my pom.xml file. I wrote this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/text/</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <username>tomcatg</username>
                    <password>sg</password>
                    <path>/firstwebapp</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I select tomcat7:deploy and press Run Maven Build button and the result is:

```
[INFO] Deploying war to http://127.0.0.1:8080/firstwebapp  
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details
```

I reviewed the web page www.slf4j.org but I don't know how to place slf4-simple.jar on the classpath and I reviewed some solutions here but I can't fix this issue.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you installed any slf4j jars within tomcat, separately from your webapp?

Comment: No, I haven't. I downloaded it but I don't know how to install it.